# Linux shell script: echo only a char, didnt handle spaces

Tags: linux, string, shell, char, whitespace

I need a command in shell script, which write a string char by char

A found 2 versions which could work:

1 with using cut

And an another, using this:

```
echo -n ${line:$j-1:1}
```

Where j is a variable of a for loop which goin true the length of the string
So this will write the string char by char, but didnt handle spaces (" ")
(i guess it didnt write null chars, but i need them)

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the expansion, so that the space isn't removed by the shell before calling `echo`:

```
echo -n "${line:$j-1:1}"
```